# Reading .nrrd file into Lua

Tags: numpy, image-processing, lua, torch

I have a .nrrd file which I can read into python and save as a np array. I want to use the resulting array in lua/torch, how would I go about this? Or is there a way of reading a .nrrd file straight into lua? Thanks.

Comment: Just found a solution for this using a package called: [npy4th](https://github.com/htwaijry/npy4th).

Answer (score 1):

As in comments, [npy4th](https://github.com/htwaijry/npy4th) should work for what you want. Anyways, i also found a python library that looks easier for this.

You can export the result into Lua in many ways, like outputting to a text file. I drop some URLs that can be helpful. As I've seen, it is pretty simple to use in Python, just with an `import nrrd` and a `frames, options = nrrd.read("test.nrrd")`.

[GitHub documentation for Pynrrd](http://github.com/mhe/pynrrd#pynnrd)

Answer (score 1):

Now you could also try [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy), essentially, you can use torch and any lua libraries in python.

The conversion will be done with `torch.fromNumpyArray(arr)`, and you will get a torch tensor. there is another function `tensor.asNumpyArray()`, helps you convert back to numpy array.

```
import lutorpy as lua
import numpy as np

xn = np.random.randn(100)
## convert the numpy array into torch tensor
tensor_xn = torch.fromNumpyArray(xn)

# you can use torch tensor as well
t = torch.DoubleTensor(10,3)
print(t._size()) # the corresponding lua version is t:size()

## convert torch tensor to numpy array
arr = t.asNumpyArray()
print(arr.shape)
```

Mostly, the conversion is done instantly with shared memory between your numpy array and torch tensor, no disk saving and even **no memory copy**.